UFW rules allow traffic from any IP to ports 80 and 443 despite specific deny rules
I am configuring UFW on my server to restrict HTTP (port 80) and HTTPS (port 443) traffic to a specific IP address while denying all other traffic. The rules work correctly for SSH (port 22), but ports 80 and 443 are still allowing traffic from any IP.
Here are my current UFW rules:
sh
root@mail:~# ufw status numbered
Status: active

     To                         Action      From
     --                         ------      ----
[ 1] 80                         ALLOW IN    192.46.*.*            
[ 2] 443                        ALLOW IN    192.46.*.*            
[ 3] 80/tcp                     DENY IN     Anywhere                  
[ 4] 443/tcp                    DENY IN     Anywhere                  
[ 5] 22                         ALLOW IN    37.*.*.*             
[ 6] 22                         ALLOW IN    192.46.*.*            
[ 7] 22                         DENY IN     Anywhere                  
[ 8] 22 (v6)                    DENY IN     Anywhere (v6)             
[ 9] 80/tcp (v6)                DENY IN     Anywhere (v6)             
[10] 443/tcp (v6)               DENY IN     Anywhere (v6)

Despite these rules, my server is still accepting connections on ports 80 and 443 from any IP address, not just 192.46...
Could someone help me understand why this is happening and how I can fix it?
Here are a few things I have already checked:
Rules Order: Confirmed that the deny rules are placed after the allow rules.
Restarted UFW: Reloaded the UFW configuration using ufw reload.
UFW Status: Verified that UFW is active and rules are listed as expected.

Any advice on what might be wrong or how to troubleshoot further would be greatly appreciated.
Not sure if this is relevant but I am running mailu in a dockerized container and want to block access to the webmail, restricting it to only my public IP

Not sure if this is relevant but I am running mailu in a dockerized container I think so, because with at least the typical setup (i.e., using a "NAT bridge" for the containers), the host basically acts as a router. In other words, traffics (from "the outside") for a container is considered "forward" traffics instead of "input" ones. (I think these days the docker engine sets up some sort of proxy at the same time but unless you disable its iptables rules, IP forwarding / DNAT prevails.) These two types of traffics are at least  filtered with different chain/hook behind the scene.

Also, the docker engine also add chains and rules to the FORWARD chain by inserting (prepending) them, while ufw appends its, so you can't really use ufw to firewall for docker containers, I think, unless you turn off docker's rules (which may lead to other complication). You may want to look into how leverage the DOCKER_USER chain.
